# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape' in Siamese LSTM network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tuples

I am designing a Siamese network for document Similarity. Google News Dataset is used for vectorization. I have used two input layers embedding and feed separate inputs to LSTM and then using Manhattan exponential function find its similarity. I have attached my model code

```
#Setting Parameters for the model



# Model variables
max_seq_length = 200
n_hidden = 50
gradient_clipping_norm = 1.25
batch_size = 64
n_epoch = 25
embedding_dim = 300
embeddings = 1 * np.random.randn() + 1, embedding_dim



class DocSim(object):
    def __init__(self, w2v_model , stopwords=[]):
        self.w2v_model = w2v_model
        self.stopwords = stopwords
        
    def vectorize(self, doc):
        """Identify the vector values for each word in the given document"""
        doc = doc.lower()
        words = [w for w in doc.split(" ") if w not in self.stopwords]
        word_vecs = []
        for word in words:
            try:
                vec = self.w2v_model[word]
                word_vecs.append(vec)
            except KeyError:
                # Ignore, if the word doesn't exist in the vocabulary
                pass

        # Assuming that the document vector is the mean of all the word vectors

        vector = np.mean(word_vecs, axis=0)
        return vector
         

    def exponent_neg_manhattan_distance(self,left, right):
        return K.exp(-K.sum(K.abs(left-right), axis=1, keepdims=True))

    # The visible layer
    left_input = Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), dtype='int32')
    right_input = Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), dtype='int32')

    embedding_layer = Embedding(len(embeddings), embedding_dim, weights=[embeddings], input_length=max_seq_length, trainable=False)

    # Embedded version of the inputs
    encoded_left = embedding_layer(left_input)
    encoded_right = embedding_layer(right_input)

    # Since this is a siamese network, both sides share the same LSTM
    shared_lstm = LSTM(n_hidden)

    left_output = shared_lstm(encoded_left)
    right_output = shared_lstm(encoded_right)

    # Calculates the distance as defined by the MaLSTM model
    malstm_distance = Lambda(function=lambda x: exponent_neg_manhattan_distance(x[0], x[1]),output_shape=lambda x: (x[0][0], 1))([left_output, right_output])

    # Pack it all up into a model
    malstm = Model([left_input, right_input], [malstm_distance])

    # Adadelta optimizer, with gradient clipping by norm
    optimizer = Adadelta(clipnorm=gradient_clipping_norm)

    malstm.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

    # Start training
    training_start_time = time()

    malstm_trained = malstm.fit([X_train['left'], X_train['right']], Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=n_epoch,
    validation_data=([X_validation['left'], X_validation['right']], Y_validation))

    print("Training time finished.\n{} epochs in {}".format(n_epoch, datetime.timedelta(seconds=time()-training_start_time)))
    
 

    def calculate_similarity(self, withdigits_source_rules, withdigits_target_rules=[], threshold=0.8):
            """Calculates & returns similarity scores between given source rules & all
            the target rules"""
            if isinstance(withdigits_target_rules, str):
                withdigits_target_rules = [withdigits_target_rules]


            source_vec = self.vectorize(withdigits_source_rules)
            results = []

            for rule in withdigits_target_rules:
                target_vec = self.vectorize(rule)
                sim_score = self.exponent_neg_manhattan_distance (source_vec, target_vec)
                if sim_score > threshold:
                    results.append({
                        'Siamese Sim Score':sim_score,
                        'Target Rule':rule
                    })


                # Sort results by score in desc order
                results.sort(key=lambda k : k['Siamese Sim Score'] , reverse=True)

            return results
```

This error is possibly because of input shape of the embedding layer. If someone can guide me with that would be great.
The error I am getting is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-2df6269816cc> in <module>
     14 
     15 
---> 16 class DocSim(object):
     17     def __init__(self, w2v_model , stopwords=[]):
     18         self.w2v_model = w2v_model

<ipython-input-4-2df6269816cc> in DocSim()
     48 
     49     # Embedded version of the inputs
---> 50     encoded_left = embedding_layer(left_input)
     51     encoded_right = embedding_layer(right_input)
     52 

~\.conda\envs\gpuversion\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
    466                 # Load weights that were specified at layer instantiation.
    467                 if self._initial_weights is not None:
--> 468                     self.set_weights(self._initial_weights)
    469 
    470             # Raise exceptions in case the input is not compatible

~\.conda\envs\gpuversion\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in set_weights(self, weights)
   1120         param_values = K.batch_get_value(params)
   1121         for pv, p, w in zip(param_values, params, weights):
-> 1122             if pv.shape != w.shape:
   1123                 raise ValueError('Layer weight shape ' +
   1124                                  str(pv.shape) +

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: When calling the `for` loop, look at this line:

```py
for pv, p, w in zip(param_values, params, weights):
```

The array or tuple `weights` must have tuples in it, not a class that has the attribute `shapes`. Make sure that all of the items in `weights` are that class.

Comment: Could you please guide me on how I can remove this error in my code. I am just beginner

Comment: @AbdulWahab Ah, yes. Sorry. Well, you know the objects of classes and tuple/lists? I hope so. In the weights list, every single item must be a class. That class must have an attribute `shape`. To fix this, first find what class has the attribute `shape`. Then, at some point in you program, print the list `weights`. Check if all of the items are that class. If not, there is your problem. You can also use a `try`/`except` statement in your code, or another loop to filter out the items that are not that specific class. I hope this helps you. =D